# What does “bien” in “ou bien” mean?

Tags: sens, conjonctions, coordination

In the following sentence, what does *bien* mean?

> Ils peuvent donner à leur enfants ou bien le nom du père ou bien le nom de la mère.

Answer (score 5):

"**Ou bien**" est utilisé dans le sens de donner un choix exclusif à l'interlocuteur.

In english it is said: "**either** this **or** that".

Une autre formulation de la phrase pourait être (exprime un choix):

> *Ils peuvent donner à leur enfants **soit** le nom du père **soit** celui de la mère*.

ou avec le **ou**  (qui sert à exprimer une alternative, une équivalence, une exclusion):

> *Ils peuvent donner à leur enfants le nom du père **ou** de la mère*.

Mais l'utilisation du "ou bien" renforce le caractère exclusif entre les deux choix.

Answer (score 4):

Here “bien” is used to reinforce the fact that you have a choice, but that it is an **exclusive or**, that is having both options is not possible.

> Maman: Il y a fromage ou dessert au menu. Que veux-tu Aline?
>
> Aline: Je veux du fromage et un dessert.
>
> Maman: Aline, tu peux prendre ou bien du fromage, ou bien un dessert, mais pas les deux.

Another example:

> Papa: Marc, pour ton anniversaire tu as le choix entre un ordinateur portable ou un ordinateur de bureau. Lequel préfères-tu?
>
> Marc: Je veux les deux ordinateurs.
>
> Papa: Non Marc, ou bien c'est un ordinateur portable, ou bien c'est un ordinateur de bureau!

Comment: Could "bien" mean "else" in this context?

Comment: No, "else" is the equivalent of "sinon". "if, then, else" is equivalent to "si, alors, sinon". In this context, "ou bien" is really equivalent to an exclusive or. The child can chose between a notebook or a desktop computer, but cannot have both of them.